# How to access user settings for a snippets extension in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to give the option to customise a VS Code Extension with user defined settings (configuration) of their preferred quote style. I have configured it in my `package.json`:

```json
"contributes": {
  "configuration": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Jasmine code snippets configuration",
    "properties": {
      "jasmineSnippets.quoteStyle": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "'",
          "\"",
          "`"
        ],
        "default": "'",
        "description": "Code snippets quote style"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

And can access it in my `settings.json` like this:

```json
"jasmineSnippets.quoteStyle": "`"
```

How can I now use that value in my `snippets.json` file? For this snippet, for example, I want to change the hardcoded ` to the configured property.

```json
"it": {
  "prefix": "it",
  "body": "it(`${1:should behave...}`, () => {\n\t$2\n});",
  "description": "creates a test method",
  "scope": "source.js"
},
```

All I could find from [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration) is not helpful as it assumes you're reading it from a JavaScript file not a JSON file:

> You can read these values from your extension using `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('myExtension')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this requires implementing a [`CompletionItemProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider) and returning the snippet from that, rather than statically declaring it in a JSON. Here's an example of what that might look like:

```ts
'use strict';
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('javascript', {
        provideCompletionItems(doc, pos, token, context) {
            var quote = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('jasmineSnippets').get("quoteStyle", "`");
            return [
                {
                    label: "it",
                    insertText: new vscode.SnippetString(
                        `it(${quote}\${1:should behave...}${quote}, () => {\n\t$2\n});`),
                    detail: "creates a test method",
                    kind: vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet,
                },
            ];
        }
    });
}
```

And then with `"jasmineSnippets.quoteStyle": "\""` in the settings:

[image]