# VS Code Extension Snippet Cache

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating an extension that is going to save snippets by just selecting the text right clicking.

I am shipping the snippets.json with the extension, but the problem is that, once the snippets.json file has the additional content/snippet, it does not appear in the command window. Once I restart VS Code, it is visible. So my question is that, is there a way to refresh VS Code Extensions cache or snippet cache?

Comment: IMO you should look into contributing snippets dynamically with a completion provider: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55140140/2631715

Comment: @Gama11 I definitely would but this is so that I do learn a little bit, and also this is for Azure Data Studio which I believe the code would be portable but I just am building this tool mostly for myself.

Comment: Well, I doubt you can do this otherwise without completely reloading VSCode (via the reload window command), which isn't much better than restarting it.

Comment: @Gama11 I think you are right... I just wanted to see if there is another way. I looked into the APIs but there wasnt any related to this.